# необходимо автоматически найти все файлы css.js,img,fonts и разместить их в соответствующие папаки

Tags: webpack, gulp, сборка, сборщик-мусора

Подскажите пожалуйста есть ли возможность у сборщиков типа webpack или Gulp отсортировать папку с проектом и упорядочить все в нужных папках с нужными путями?
Поясню:
1 вариант задачи:
есть проект ( мой проект ) в папке лежат файл картинок, скриптов, стилей и html файл (все на одном уровне), а мне необходимо, чтоб был html файл, папка стилей в которой лежит стилевой файл, папка картинок в которой лежат картинки и так далее. И  плюс , чтоб автоматически правились пути к нужным файлам.

2 вариант задачи:
Очень большая вложенность т.е. попка с проектом . и пошла череда вложенных папок (папка 1/папка2/папка3/папка4/папка5/.../файлы) роезультат нужен как и в первой задаче. Буду очень плагодарен за развернутый ответ детальный ответ с примерами т.к. технологиями указанными выше не владею. Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Да, на примере Gulp решение 1-задачи:

В моем случае текущий конфигурационный файл называется gulpfile.js.

```
const {src, dest, series, watch} = require('gulp');
const sync = require('browser-sync').create()

...

// Здесь идет поиск всех файлов из папки app с расширением html и сборка в папку html
function html() {
  return src('app/**/*.html')
    .pipe(dest('docs/html'));
}

// Здесь идет поиск всех файлов из папки app с расширением css и сборка в папку css
function css() {
  return src('app/**/*.css')
    .pipe(dest('docs/css'))
}

// Здесь идет поиск всех файлов из папки app с расширением js и сборка в папку js
    function js() {
      return src('app/**/*.js')
        .pipe(dest('docs/js'))
    }

// Здесь идет поиск всех картинок из папки app и сборка в папку img
    function img() {
      return src(['app/**/*.jpg', 'app/**/*.png'])
        .pipe(dest('docs/img'));
    
    }

... 

// Здесь уже запускаем функции, которых выше объявляли:
function serve() {
  sync.init({
    port: 3010,
    reloadOnRestart: true,
    server: {
      baseDir: 'docs',
      directory: true
    }
  });

  watch('app/**/*.html', series(html)).on('change', sync.reload);
  watch('app/**/*.css', series(css, html)).on('change', sync.reload);
  watch('app/**/*.js', series(js)).on('change', sync.reload);
  watch(['app/**/*.jpg', 'app/**/*.png'], series(img)).on('change', sync.reload);
}

exports.build = series(css, js, img, html);
exports.watch = series(css, js, img, html, serve);
```

Для запуска прописать в терминале `gulp watch`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1423509/507388 Спасибо, буду пробовать!